# PowerShell Invoke RestMethod response as file to PDF

Tags: powershell, pdf, invoke-command

I am using invoke-restmethod `GET` in **Powershell** which produces a **PDF** file as a response.
I can see that file as an encoded format in the **PowerShell** window.

I need to create a **PDF** file from the response.

> How to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-OutFile` parameter:

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method Get -OutFile output.pdf
```

Comment: I have used -Outfile and got the pdf file but it is not opening. May be issue with encode